# How to get google review reply using PHP my business api?

Tags: php, google-api, google-my-business-api

I am using the PHP Google MyBusiness API for my application. I have business reviews.

Now I want to get any replies related to a particular review. I am able to post a reply, but I want to get replies (responses) for the review using PHP GMB API.

How do I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/get) in the response you get `reviewReply` object which holds your reply

```
{
  "reviewId": string,
  "reviewer": {
    object(Reviewer)
  },
  "starRating": enum(StarRating),
  "comment": string,
  "createTime": string,
  "updateTime": string,
  "reviewReply": {
    object(ReviewReply)
  },
}
```

[more info](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews#Review)

to get the review use the get method of `Google_Service_MyBusiness_AccountsLocationsReviews_Resource`

```
class Google_Service_MyBusiness_AccountsLocationsReviews_Resource extends Google_Service_Resource
{

  /**
   * Returns the specified review. This operation is only valid if the specified
   * location is verified. Returns `NOT_FOUND` if the review does not exist, or
   * has been deleted. (reviews.get)
   *
   * @param string $name The name of the review to fetch.
   * @param array $optParams Optional parameters.
   * @return Google_Service_MyBusiness_Review
   */
  public function get($name, $optParams = array())
  {
    $params = array('name' => $name);
    $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
    return $this->call('get', array($params), "Google_Service_MyBusiness_Review");
  }
```

Comment: Using PHP how to get it? I am not getting how to pass reviewID,location etc.. in https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/get

Comment: i think the name param is the reviewID, the documentation is unclear